# Biblatex: Refer to footnote of first citation in citestyle verbose-ibid

Tags: biblatex

I would like to get Biblatex to do the following: I want citations in footnotes. When they occur first time, full information (author, title, year and so on) should be shown. When they occur a second time in the paper they should be cited with authorname and shorttitle, and with a reference to the footnote of the first full-citation should be given. So for example:

```
A favourite work of Thedor W. Adorno is "Dialektik der Aufklärung"¹ which he wrote together with Max Horkheimer. 
Some people say "Negative Dialektik"² is the main oeuvre of Theodor W. Adorno.
But let's discuss "Dialektik der Aufklärung"³ first.  
___________

¹ Max Horkheimer and Theodor W. Adorno: Dialektik der Aufklärung. Philosophische Fragmente. 17.th Edition, Frankfurt am Main: Fischer, 2009
² Theodor W. Adorno. *Negative Dialektik* Frankfurt am Main: Suhrkamp, 2003
³ Max Horkheimer and Theodor W. Adorno: Dialektik der Aufklärung. (see footnote 1), p. 12
```

I have already found citestyle verbose-ibid which responds nearly perfect to my needs. The only thing I am still searching is how I get the automatic reference to the footnote with the first citation. Can someone tell me how? Thank you ever so much!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is a `biblatex` standard style that does this: [`verbose-inote`](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/biblatex/doc/examples/73-style-verbose-inote.pdf) (or [`verbose-note`](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/biblatex/doc/examples/72-style-verbose-note.pdf), if you do not want ibid-capabilities).

If you always want to see the (short) title, we better add the option `singletitle=false`; if we leave the default `singletitle=true`, authors with only one work will not have the title printed in further citations.

MWE

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[british]{babel}
\usepackage{csquotes}
\usepackage[style=verbose-inote,singletitle=false]{biblatex}

\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}

\begin{document}
  O Fortuna\footcite{cicero} velut luna statu variabilis,\footcite{wilde}
  semper crescis aut decrescis;\footcite{cicero} 
  vita detestabilis nunc obdurat et tunc curat ludo mentis
  aciem, egestatem, potestatem dissolvit ut glaciem.\footcite{cicero}

  \printbibliography
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I see this questions several months after it was posted because I was trying to find an answer to the same problem. A publisher requires exactly this system because they do not want a final bibliography and the reader should know where to locate the complete citation (bizarre systems indeed).

At the moment I am doing this manually:

```
% EXAMPLE-BEGIN
Kant noticed that so and so%
\footnote{See \cite[\label{}23]{Kant:KRV}}. 
more text here ...
\newpage
As already noticed%
\footnote{Again by Kant: \cite[(see footnote~\ref{Kant:KRV}), 127]{Kant:KRV}}%
, more text here.
% EXAMPLE-END
```

but if there is nothing better around a new macro for this should not difficult to design. Has this issue never been dealt with?

Thanks a lot!